# How to use Android's AlarmManager in kivy to make a *function/class* of kivy program to run at given time?

Tags: android, kivy, kivy-language, pyjnius, kivymd

I believe we can make use of android's AlarmManager to run some code at given time. I want to run one function or one class of my kivy program at given time. Is this possible ? If yes, then please help me out. If no, then atleast help me to run the apk itself at given time.

Comment: It's probably possible, but I don't know how much effort you'll have to put in to work with the api (e.g. maybe you have to handle an intent). Ultimately you'll need to call the relevant java api with pyjnius.

Comment: I am absolute beginner to Android development. So I don't know much about handling intent.